# SharePoint 2016 Search WebControls assembly?

Tags: sharepoint-2016

I am wondering where the assembly for the webcontrol has gone to.
In SharePoint 2013 there was Microsoft.Office.Server.Search (in Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.dll).

Now for SHarePoint 2016 there appears to be a new assembly called Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.dll. That's fine. Just the WebControls namespace is empty!

Any idea where controls like **ResultScriptWebPart**, **DataProviderScriptWebPart** or **RefinementScriptWebPart** can no be found at?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the old DLL still exists but is not visible in the "add reference" dialog in Visual Studio by default. You can add it manually: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.dll

I have yet to investigate what the difference between these two assemblies is (apparently KeywordQuery class for example is implemented in both assemblies - different implementation?)